# Facebook Comments widget makes page jump to bottom in IE7 IE8

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, internet-explorer, loading

I have a fairly long page with the Facebook comments widget at the bottom. With this widget in place the page jumps to the bottom on loading in IE7 and IE8. Whenever I remove the widget the page loads normally. This doesn't happen on any other browser. Can anyone suggest any way to prevent this? I've tried appending the .fb-comments div and calling FB.XFBML.parse() on it on document ready, but the behaviour in this case is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Facebook bug. I think they are working on it. If you go to the developers area on FB is a thread discussing it.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Also occurs in IE9, no updates in the last weeks for my web applications, should be a facebook bug or IE bug